# use PagedList as ViewModel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

i wanna use PageList.

before :

MyClass:

```
 public class Feachers
    {
  public List<Project.Models.view_Student> Players { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int day { get; set; }
        public int month { get; set; }
        public int year { get; set; }
     }

    }
```

View :

```
  @model Project.Models.AllClasses.MyClass.Feachers
  ...
  // I have some drop-downlists and textbox in view. And fill my model by them (name ,day, month,…)
```

Now I wanna change my code . I used

```
 @model PagedList.IPagedList< Project.Models.AllClasses.MyClass.Feachers>
```

in my view instead  @model Project.Models.AllClasses.MyClass.Feachers .

but i lost my properties (name , day , ...).
i should specific work?

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a view model:

```
public class FeachersViewModel
{
    public IPagedList<Project.Models.view_Student> Players { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int day { get; set; }
    public int month { get; set; }
    public int year { get; set; }
}
```

and your view will be strongly typed to this view model:

```
@model FeachersViewModel
```

Now in the view you could use the `@Model.Players` property which will be a PagedList. Now all that's left is adapt your contorller action to populate and pass the view model to the view instead of your domain model (which is best practice anyways).

Comment: but in this way PageNumber and PageSize are peroperties that are  for Players( Model.Players.PageNumber) . it should not belonge for complete model? in my cod  i mean for Feachers ?

Comment: If they are properties for Players, then write a PlayerViewModel, include them to this view model and then make an `PagedList<PlayerViewModel>`.

Comment: no they are not for players . when declare PagedList , they are produced automatically . is'n it?

Comment: in my way i just have PageSize,PageNumber ,TotalItemCount ,...and don't have my property(name , day , ...)

Comment: Design and use a view model depending on what you need to pass to your view. That's what view models are intended for. whatever information your view needs, you should include it in your view model.